# List (range(2,10,-1)) returns an empty list

Tags: python, list, range

range(whatever) returns range(whatever) very well.
The thing is, if I call list on range(start,stop,"NEGATIVE STEP"), then it returns an empty list.

So,

```
>>>range(2,10,-1)
range(2,10,-1)
```

However,

```
>>>list(range(2,10,-1))
[ ]
```

while

```
>>>list(range(2,10,3))
[2,5,8]
```

Do you have any idea on Why it is and How I resolve this?

Comment: How could 2 plus a negative number equals 10?? Did you try `list(range(10, 2, -1))`?

Comment: If the step is negative the start gas to be greater than the end.

Comment: If you put step a negative number then you have to give start value which is greater than end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct is:
`list(range(10,2,-1))`
you start form 10 and you want to go to 2, not the opposite.
By doing range(2,10,-1) you start form 2 and you want to go until 10 with step of -1 which is impossible so the resolt is an empty one

Answer (score 0):

the third part is the incrementing part ie here

```
list(range(2,10,3))
```

get output 2,2+3,2+3+3 [2,5,8]
 in this case list(range(2,10,-1))
since the range is between 2 to 10, you cannot decrement it by  -1

so you have to do like this list(range(10,2,-1))  ,then you will get output as [10,9,8,....3 ]

so try this `list(range(10,2,-1))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how range works....
range can take three args. range({start}:{end}:{step})

```
start = inclusive i.e list(range(0:2))=> returns [0, 1] so start is 
inclusive.

end = exclusive (end-1 is inclusive) i.e list(range(0:2)) => returns [0, (2-
1)]

step = increment value (by default its 1, -1 means decrement)
```

When you do list(range(2,10,-1)) i.e it starts from 2(inclusive) and goes till (10-1) but you said decrement it by 1 (i.e step is -1). So it doesn't make sense as you will never reach 10 by this way. As pointed by @stravos make it

```
list(range(10,2,-1))
```

decrement makes sense only from higher to lower.